# Compiling Armadillo C++ Project to WebAssembly (WASM)

Tags: c++, emscripten, armadillo

I have developed a C++ project that heavily relies on the Armadillo library for numerical computations. Now, I am interested in converting this project into a WebAssembly (WASM) module so that it can be utilized in a web-based application. I am seeking guidance on how to successfully compile my Armadillo-based C++ project into a WASM module.

Here's a brief overview of my project setup:

- I am using the Armadillo library for linear algebra and numerical calculations.
- My project consists of multiple C++ source files and includes the necessary Armadillo header files.

Specifically, I'm looking for assistance with the following:

- Steps to configure the Emscripten SDK and set up the environment for compiling to WebAssembly.
- How to correctly install Armadillo for Emscripten and ensure its compatibility with WebAssembly.
- Modifications or considerations I need to make to my existing C++ code to ensure it works well in the WebAssembly environment.
- The compilation command using emcc to generate a WebAssembly module while linking the Armadillo library.